# meteor restivus endpoints configuration

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, http, meteor

so i have meteor running and i wish to expose a REST API. i decided to choose restivus as it seemed a bit cleaner and more flexible to me.

so my basic code is:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    // Sensors = new Meteor.Collection('sensor');

    Restivus.configure({
      useAuth: false,
      prettyJson: false
    });
    Restivus.addCollection("sensor", {
      defaultOptions: {},
    });

  });
}
```

and i can query it fine using:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/sensor
{"status":"success","data":[{"_id":{"_str":"00000000236668afaf952dee"},"ts":1424246899,"temp":28,"humidity":33}]}
```

hmm... so the '_id' i manually enter (rather than letting mongo set it for me) looks a bit strange in the output; but okay, i guess it's an `ObjectId()`. however, when i go about with a GET, it fails:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/sensor/00000000236668afaf952dee
```

{"status":"fail","message":"Item not found"}

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Also, there was a mistake in the docs that has since been fixed; so the object you've declared as `defaultOptions: {}` should actually be named `routeOptions`, not that it would matter here since you haven't actually set any options. Just wanted to point that out so it doesn't bite you elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the _id is actually an Object `{"_str":"0000....52dee"}` rather than the simple string `"0000....52dee"`. The problem is most likely in the code where you save the _id. It should look like this `{"_id" : "rdSRTTz5RL5JjQy3G"}`.

Comment: yeah, i deleted the doc in mongo and created it directly through the REST api and it's fine now. funny thing was i actually created the doc in mongo using `ObjectId()` - is this not recommended?

Comment: I typically let MongoDB assign one on insert. Occasionally, I use a library to generate a UUID string. Will you please accept the answer?